# Need help understanding decimal datatype error

Tags: sql, types, decimal

Why does the first code throw an error, but the second code block does not?

```
DECLARE @Decimal DECIMAL(4, 4)

SELECT @Decimal = 1.98761

SELECT @Decimal
GO

DECLARE @Decimal DECIMAL(5, 4)

SELECT @Decimal = 1.98761

SELECT @Decimal
```

Comment: You should format the code and post the full error message (not just in the title.

Answer (score 3):

You are misinterpreting precision and scale.

`DECIMAL(4,4)` has four digits of precision and . . .  they are all to the right of the decimal place.  So, it can contain values between 0.0000 and 0.9999.

The value 1.98761 exceeds that range.  Hence, an error.